# Check if a dictionary value contains a list item

Tags: python, list, dictionary, for-loop, list-comprehension

I have a dictionary which has a key (a two digit prefix) and a value (a list of strings). It looks something like this:

```
prefixes = {
    "AC" : ["england-wales"],
    "OC" : ["england-wales", "wales"],
    "SC" : ["scotland"],
    "NC" : ["northern-ireland"]
}
```

I am trying to create a list of prefixes in which the value contains a region provided in a list.

The region passed through can be one or more regions, for example:

```
regions = ['england-wales', 'wales']
```

So, with the above data I would like to create a new list called prefixes and it will contain all the prefixes where **either** 'wales' or 'england-wales' is included in the value:

```
prefix_list = ['AC', 'OC']
```

Whereas if regions is just equal to 'wales' then:

```
prefix_list = ['OC']
```

I have played around with a few things and got this messy solution working:

```
combo_list = []
prefix_list = []

for r in regions:
    combo_list.append([k for k, v in prefixes.items() if r in v])

for sublist in combo_list:
    for i in sublist:
        prefix_list.append(i)

prefix_list = sorted(set(prefix_list)) #This will remove duplicates for me
```

I think there must be a better, 'cleaner' way of doing this but can't quite figure it out. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`any()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) for this - as a list comprehension:

```
prefix_list = [k for k, v in prefixes.items() if any(x in v for x in regions)]
```

Gives us

```
>>> prefix_list
['AC', 'OC']
```